# Find the cell value that intersects two strings in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering how I can get excel to find a value based on a string in a column and a string in a row. For example

```
         a73hfj     a384asd     a848fjs

a          x1          x2          x3

b          y1          y2          y3

c          z1          z2          z3
```

How can I find y2 by specifying that it is in the row of b and the column of a384asd?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these.

R1C1 mode:

```
=INDEX(R2C2:R4C4,MATCH("b",R2C1:R4C1,0),MATCH("a384asd",R1C2:R1C4,0))
```

A1 mode:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH("b",$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH("a384asd",$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also works...

```
=OFFSET(A1,LOOKUP(C1,B1:D1,ROW(A1:A3)),LOOKUP(C1,A2:A41,ROW(A1:A3)))
```